# How do I force a selection of items to a specific user/database row?

Tags: database-design

I have a database that allows a company to register, then the user of the company can register individual "user" accounts.

The company administrator (who sets up the company account) can log in with a password, however, the user accounts he/she then creates are assigned a smart card based on a smart card serial number.

this works, however, I would like to restrict the selection of smart cards to those only that have been issued for the selected "company".

Currently, I have a form that allows me to create a range of smart cards.

I have a drop down look up for the user that allows me to select a smart card, however, it will show all available smart cards that I have created.

When would it best be places, and how would it best be achieved to ensure only a range of smart cards are available when a company administrator is creating individual accounts?

I have uploaded a pic of my current schema and I am currently using Microsoft access for concept design but will be moving to SQL and using asp.net.

Thanks in advance.[image]
Stephen

Comment: The only reason I'm commenting is because this seems too simple - couldn't you just add BusinessID to the SmartCard table?

Comment: I think I could, but I thought that I was overlooking something, that it seemed almost to easy to be the option. I think I am overthinking my design. Thank you